# Is there any html parser for yaws?

Tags: erlang, yaws, mochiweb

I am writing an application in erlang on [yaws](http://yaws.hyber.org/) server. I want to extract data from some html page but their seems to be no good way to do this on yaws. There is a method using [mochiweb_html](https://github.com/mochi/mochiweb/blob/master/src/mochiweb_html.erl) but then it is for mochiweb server and not yaws. What should I do? Can mochiweb_html be used in yaws somehow?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Yaws is a server, and thus intended to serve pages. 
Mochiweb is basically a library of web server related functions. Is there a real need for you to use Yaws because I think Mochiweb would suit your purpose quite well?

Comment: Actually I have already completed so much of work using yaws as server. Now I have no idea how should I proceed if I want to use mochiweb library.

Comment: Without knowing the details of your problem: Importing the module mochiweb and using the right functions in it is as easy as using any other Erlang module.

Comment: Oh, I just tried it and it worked. I always thought that mochiweb library can only be used if you are running mochiweb server. Thank you so much and really sorry for asking a silly question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the functionality of Mochiweb modules as any ordinary Erlang module. You don't need to be running Mochiweb server to do that.

Answer (score 2):

The [`yaws_html.erl` file](https://github.com/klacke/yaws/blob/master/src/yaws_html.erl) in the Yaws source provides basic HTML parsing capabilities.